# "Transpose" result of combn in R

Tags: r

I have a:

```
mylist <- list("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
```

and I want to get combination of twos here:

```
c2 <- combn(mylist, 2)
```

wherein I get

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,] "a"  "a"  "a"  "a"  "b"  "b"  "b"  "c"  "c"  "d"  
[2,] "b"  "c"  "d"  "e"  "c"  "d"  "e"  "d"  "e"  "e"
```

But I want to transpose this list, so I can loop through each pair. How do I do that?

Comment: you can still loop through each pair as every pair is a separate column. By transpose do you mean `t(combn(mylist, 2))` . Moreover, there is `FUN` argument in `combn` using which you can apply a function to each pair directly.

Comment: you can loop through the columns using `apply(c2,2, yourfunction` or `for (i in 1:ncol(c2)){ yourfunction(c2[,i])}`

Comment: you should use `expand.grid`

Comment: what are you trying to do with each pair? For example try using `combn(mylist, 2, toString)` it creates a comma -separated string for each combination.

Comment: @RonakShah you're example is enough, thanks. Sorry, hope no one would downvote me as I came from Python and the mix up between R and Python is confusing.

Comment: You can also use `simplify = FALSE` to get a list instead of a matrix: `combn(mylist, 2, simplify = FALSE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply use `t()` to transpose it

```
c2 <- t(combn(mylist, 2))
```